# Duplicate index names with DBIx::Class and PostgreSQL

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbix-class

I have an existing MySQL database which I'm trying to migrate to PostgreSQL using the following steps. The database is fairly simple - it has a few foreign keys and other constraints but no triggers, procedures etc.

1. Use `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` to produce a set of `Result` classes from the existing MySQL database.
2. Use the `Result` classes to produce a set of `CREATE TABLE` statements for PostgreSQL.
3. Run the `CREATE TABLE` statements using `psql` to set up the tables (I haven't got as far as data importing yet).

The script I am using is as follows (with credentials and DB name removed):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw/ make_schema_at /;

my $dsn = 'dbi:mysql:dbname=database';
my $user = '';
my $pass = '';

make_schema_at(
  'MyDB::Schema',
  { debug => 1, dump_directory => './lib' },
  [ $dsn, $user, $pass
  ],
);

my $schema = MyDB::Schema->connect($dsn, $user, $pass);
$schema->create_ddl_dir(['PostgreSQL'], '0.1', './', undef, { add_drop_table => 0 });
```

The script runs successfully, and both the `Result` classes and the `.sql` file (containing all the `CREATE TABLE` statements) look as I would expect.

However, several tables have a `slug` column which is marked as `UNIQUE` in the original MySQL schema, and results in the following lines as part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
"slug" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "slug" UNIQUE ("slug")
```

When I attempt to import the data (using `psql < tables.sql`), I get the following error on every table with a unique `slug` column after the first:

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / UNIQUE will create implicit index "slug" for table "mytable"
ERROR:  relation "slug" already exists
```

My understanding is that index names have to be unique within a given database. I don't have this problem with MySQL as I just declare `slug VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE` without specifying an index name.

Is there a way to make `DBIx::Class` (or `SQL::Translator`, which the `create_ddl_dir` function uses) generate a unique index name in the data it outputs? I don't particularly care what the indexes are called - though something based on the table name would be sensible. I've looked through the documentation but I can't see any parameters which allow this.

I could just edit every constraint manually before importing the `.sql` file, but there are over 250 tables and a lot of clashes - plus I would have to do this every time I tweaked the migration process and had to regenerate the classes and SQL.

Comment: Have you tried to run `SQL::Translator` on your MySQL schema directly without going through `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`?

Comment: Same problem - it outputs the same SQL which results in duplicate index names.

Comment: It seems that you created named unique constraints in your MySQL schema. It should work to use unnamed constraints by simple using `UNIQUE` in the column definition.

Comment: That is how I created the constraints in MySQL (i.e. just using UNIQUE), however when you take a database dump and pass it through SQL::Translator it generates named unique constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only automated way to fix this was with a Perl script that forced every constraint name (and thus the automatic index) to be unique by parsing the output from `SQL::Translator` and appending `_$i` to each name, where `$i` is incremented each time a new constraint is seen.

Code is as follows - assumes you will pipe the schema in on `STDIN`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;

my $i = 1;

while (my $line = <>)
{
  if ($line =~ m/CONSTRAINT\s+"([a-zA-Z_]+)"\s+UNIQUE\s+\("([a-zA-Z_]+)"\)/)
  {    
    my $constraint_name = $1 . '_' . $i;
    my $column_name = $2;

    my $replace_str = 'CONSTRAINT "' . $constraint_name . '" UNIQUE ("' . $column_name . '")';

    $line =~ s/CONSTRAINT\s+"([a-zA-Z_]+)"\s+UNIQUE\s+\("([a-zA-Z_]+)"\)/$replace_str/;
    $i++;
  }

  print $line;
}
```